# My DLL causes a "Caution you are attempting to open a file of type "Applicaiont Extension" .dll at boot

Tags: vb.net, dll, wix

On a Windows 7 x64 I have have written an application which also includes a .dll which is installed to the GAC. This has been working without error for about 3 years. I recently made a new version of my Application but did not change the version of the .dll.  The application starts at boot time and now I get a message from Windows...

> Caution ... You are attempting to open a file of type "Application Extension" .dll

And then it wants you to choose a program to run it with.

I uninstalled this version and installed my previous version and I do not get the error.

I have no idea where the problem is so my tags are an attempt to get the ball rolling. Wix is my installer program which might have something to do with it.

**How is my Application started at boot time**
There is a registry entry in \Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run which has a path to the Application's .exe file.  This Applicaion has the dll as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

So if you remove it from autostart and start it after the pc is fully up, does the same message appear ? If that worked, a workaround would be registering your app as a service and set its startup to delayed. 
When i googled your error some malware- threads came up. If you straight up load your dll and its unsigned e.g. via rundll32.exe that might cause an issue - but i dont entirely know how your autostart-entrypoint looks like.

Comment: Googling is difficult as I also get all malware results. If I start my application myself (eg double clicking the .exe file) there is no problem.  (see my edits for your other question)

Comment: I still have not got a solution to this. Do you have any idea why it is doing this? Is the program being started before the assembly is ready? I would like to understand the problem first before trying to solve it with for example a service which I would prefer not to do.